# Generic within a generic in Swift

Tags: swift

Trying to make sense of the code below.
I understand that T is passed by when instantiating the Optional, as in Optional, but what about the U type in map.  What type does that assume?

```
enum Optional<T> : LogicValue, Reflectable {
    case None
    case Some(T)
    init()
    init(_ some: T)

    /// Allow use in a Boolean context.
    func getLogicValue() -> Bool

    /// Haskell's fmap, which was mis-named
    func map<U>(f: (T) -> U) -> U?
    func getMirror() -> Mirror
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type `U` comes from the `f` parameter to the `map` function. So if you pass a closure that returns a `Int`, then `map` returns a `Int?`. If you pass a closure that returns a `Array<Int>`, then `map` returns a `Array<Int>?`.

For example, try this:

```
var opt1: Optional<Int> = .Some(1)
var opt2 = opt1.map { (i: Int) -> String in return "String: \(i)" }
```

You'll find that `opt1` is an `Int?` and `opt2` is a `String?`.

Answer (score 4):

When calling the `map` function the caller must provide a single argument which is a closure that:

1. Has a single argument that is the same type as the one used to
   instantiate `Optional`, i.e. `T`
2. Has a return value of some type.

`U` will then be the type of said return value.