# How to get an enumeration's value's value?

Tags: enums, swift, option-type

In Apple's "A swift Tour" they have this code snippet:

```
enum OptionalValue<T> {
    case None
    case Some(T)
}
var possibleInteger: OptionalValue<Int> = .None
possibleInteger = .Some(100)
```

How would you get the 100? You can't do `possibleInteger == 100` to test if `possibleInteger` has the value 100 inside. I know you can put functions inside enumerations, but you can't have variables. Maybe I'm understanding enumerations wrong…

If I command click `Optional` when declaring an optional (`var x:Optional<Int>`), I can find

```
enum Optional<T> : Reflectable, NilLiteralConvertible {
    case None
    case Some(T)
    init()
    init(_ some: T)

    /// Haskell's fmap, which was mis-named
    func map<U>(f: (T) -> U) -> U?
    func getMirror() -> MirrorType
    static func convertFromNilLiteral() -> T?
}
```

But I do not understand what any of that means. Help?

Comment: After much research, I need to implement the `getMirror()` function. This will let you show the value in playground, which I was trying to do. Well, off to research this "MirrorType" thing.
Also, `convertFromNilLiteral() -> T?` just sets the enum to `.None` when you set it to nil. I still have no clue what `func map<U>(f: (T) -> U) -> U?` does.

Comment: Re: `func map...`, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24395211/generic-within-a-generic-in-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `switch` statement to get the value, [as described here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-XID_227). Relevant bit:

> ... the associated values can be extracted as part of the switch
>   statement. You extract each associated value as a constant (with the
>   let prefix) or a variable (with the var prefix) for use within the
>   switch case’s body:

For your case, you'd want something like:

```
switch possibleInteger {
case .Some(let value):
    println(value)
case .None:
    println("<None>")
}
```

Comment: Wow I did not think of making a variable within .Some :o… So how would I go about making that value show up on the left side in a playground? It is by implementing getMirror(), right?

Comment: I think you're right that you'd have to implement the `Reflectable` protocol for that to work. I haven't tried that, but it looks fairly involved.